# Support-Screens in Manifest File

Tags: android, android-screen-support

This is my code in my android manifest file.

```
supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"
```

What I understand from supportscreens is that it can be used to simply fit the app screen onto the multiple screen sizes done by resizing it and stretching the image. However, I don't see any difference with or without this code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: FYI, I believe as of Android 3.2, these were replaced with just `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp`, `android:compatibleWidthLimitDp`, and `android:largestWidthLimitDp`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element