# What it is the use of support-screen tag in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-screen-support

Hello I am trying to target only `Android` phones only. I got to know `compatible-screen` tag can help me to achieve this. I see there is another tag `support-screen`.

Is there any use of it in Android ? What it does ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps The latter of those links is to another section on the same page that I linked to in my previous answer to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare I would appreciate if you answer here so that it would be great for future readers also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [**Developers-Site**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)::      ***Use these lines below in your manifest***

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

---

***Using these lines will make your app to work only on handsets !***

*Hope this Clears your Question !*

---

### {EDIT} - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463634/support-screens-in-manifest-file)

```
 /res/layout/layout.xml         // Default layout
 /res/layout-small/layout.xml   // Small screens
 /res/layout-large/layout.xml   // Large screens
 /res/layout-xlarge/layout.xml  // Ex
```

You can go even further and make also different layouts for portrait and landscape views by specyfing another keyword in directory's name:

```
 /res/layout-small-land/layout.xml      // Small screens, landscape view
 /res/layout-small-portrait/layout.xml  // Small screens, portrait view
```

Remember that tags order is important, so you can't write layout-portrait-small.

And in last add this code to your manifest file:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"  
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

**whenever you run application in any device according to that screen size that layout called**

Comment: I didn't ask that which you answered :). I asked I see there is another tag support-screen.

Is there any use of it in Android ? What it does ?

Comment: Check this link ......... http://stackoverflow.com/q/17463634/1083093 .... and here http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: Thanks can you please update your answer so that I will accept it. My question is what it is the use of `support-screen` do even we have already `compatible-screen` tag