# Android release in play market

Tags: android, apache, release

I post my application in play market and I get compatible platform as common-io.jar and compatible devices is 0. I tried a lot of approaches but still cannot solve this problem. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in to your mainfest

```
<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Please refer this link [Support-Screens in Manifest File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463634/support-screens-in-manifest-file)