# Support-Screen Manifest with multiple layouts

Tags: java, android, compatibility, android-studio-3.0

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463634/support-screens-in-manifest-file) but which is not clear to me is ;
When having many layouts with fragments as well, how to add

```
/res/layout/layout.xml         // Default layout
 /res/layout-small/layout.xml   // Small screens
 /res/layout-large/layout.xml   // Large screens
 /res/layout-xlarge/layout.xml  // Ex

/res/layout-small-land/layout.xml      // Small screens, landscape view
 /res/layout-small-portrait/layout.xml  // Small screens, portrait view
```

To make the app compatible with any screen sizes? Also for one UI is it required to design required view x6(layout,small,large,xlarge,small-land,small-portrait) times of the screen sizes?

Comment: This should help: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Thank you i have already noticed that. Instead of using that but my concern is when using "<**support-screen**> as i understood it is required to define mentioned layouts for different sizes. If so when there are multiple layouts is it required to create four times layout per one UI ?

Comment: No you shouldn't need to.  I usually just test them on different screen sizes and if I see something is not fitting or needs fixing.  I copy the UI layout into the folder and then modify what needs fixing.  Sometimes you can just use different dimensions files instead of having to have a whole new layout.  
See the answer on this page for an example of how to use dimensions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: Mm.. I got it. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can check this :

res/layout/main_activity.xml                # For handsets
res/layout-land/main_activity.xml           # For handsets in landscape
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml        # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw600dp-land/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets in landscape
```